# Virtual device in android studio virtual device manager is not play protect certified

Tags: android-studio, play-protect, google-play-protect

I downloaded Android Studio yesterday, so it should be fairly new.

I created 2 virtual devices using latest SDK, version 14 something.

Both device is not play protect certified when I check in:

Play Store --> Profile --> Settings --> About

We can never certify any virtual device in android studio?

How can I certify my virtual device in android studio?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Android studio but I am aware of `MEETS_VIRTUAL_INTEGRITY` field in apps testing for integrity

Quoting from [Integrity protection for Google Play Games on PC for PC](https://developer.android.com/games/playgames/integrity):

> The `deviceRecognitionVerdict` field contains a single value, `deviceRecognitionVerdict`, that represents how well a device can enforce app integrity

It goes on to describe the different types and relevant to your question

> `MEETS_VIRTUAL_INTEGRITY`: The app is running in a **virtual** Android environment with Google Play services, **currently limited to Google Play Games on PC**.

(Emphasis supplied)

Screen shot from [TB checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=krypton.tbsafetychecker), which I use for checking device integrity, just as FYI

[image]

Comment: If this answer is not relevant (since I never used Android studio), any reader is welcome to point it out and I will delete it